# Cast Class<object> to Class<T>

Tags: c#, .net, casting

We have a generic class called `Context<T> where T : class`, and create another class `Message` to be used together with the previous one as `Context<Message>`.
Generally speaking, we are wondering if there is a way to convert a `Context<object>` back to `Context<Message>`.
We can do a check that the object is of type Message,
but doing `Context<Message> context = (Context<Message>) otherContext;` where otherContext is `Context<object>`

Is this possible in some way?

Comment: Just because two types `T1` and `T2` have a particular inheritance relationship, that does NOT mean that a generic parameterized with those two types (`G<T1>` and `G<T2>`) exhibits the *same* inheritance relationship.

Comment: `Class<object>` is not the same as `Class<Message>`. Create a new `Class<Message>` instance and put `Message` parameter (casted from `obejct`) to the ctor. There is [generic type covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) but you have to modify the `Class<T>` source code

Comment: If you can make it 'public class Context<in T>' then you should be allowed to make the cast. However this puts restrictions on how 'T' is used in the 'Context' class. If you want to know more search for covariance and invariance. Plenty of information about this.

Comment: @Knoop covariance and invariance are only for interface and delegate types not class type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer cast, try this:

```
class YourClass<T> where T : class
{
    public static implicit operator YourClass<T>(YourClass<object> instance)
    {
        // Create YourClass<T> from YourClass<object>
        // e.g. return new YourClass<T>(...)
    }
}

var obj = new YourClass<object>();
YourClass<Message> msg = obj;
```

Otherwise, you could create a constructor:

```
class YourClass<T> where T : class
{
    public YourClass(YourClass<object> obj)
    {

    }
}
```

Or you can have both.